# Reading a .txt file having lines starting with special characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to read in every line in a file that starts with different special characters. I don't want to read those special characters just the rest of the line that follows.
The records are presented in the file like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njvlQ.png)
Then I need to store each document in a dataframe's row.

This is what I tried:

```
Doc = namedtuple('Doc', 'venue year authors title id references abstract')
docs = []

with open('/content/test.txt') as f:
  for l in f.readlines():
   ln = l.rstrip('\n')
   if  ln.startswith('#c'):
    venue = ln[2:]
    #print(venue)
   if  ln.startswith('#t'):
     year = ln[2:]
     #print(year)
   if  ln.startswith('#@'):
     authors = []
     author = ln[2:]
     authors.append(author)
   if  ln.startswith('#*'):
     title = ln[2:]
   if  ln.startswith('#index'):
     id = ln[2:]
   if ln.startswith('#%'):
        references = []
        reference = ln[2:]
        references.append(reference)
   if  ln.startswith('#!'):
     abstract = ln[2:]
     print(abstract)
     docs.append(Doc(venue, year, authors, title, id, references, abstract))

   df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(docs, columns= 
   ['Venue','Year','Authors','Title','id', 'ListCitations','Abstract'])
df
```

Can someone help me to solve the problem of variables storing in a list as authors and references? Thank you

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: What's the problem with your code? What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? What debugging steps have you taken? Please take the [tour] and read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: The problem is that the variables authors and references must be a list but they contain only one element

Comment: As a suggestion, instead of writing so many ```if-logic```, try using ```re module```.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed all issue###########

Fixed the code i guess u are missing some references so I just imported them. Also
before running the code u might want to install below mentioned package called pandas

I am currently using python 3.8, if your using the python 2 version then u might want to skip the 3 in pip command

```
pip3 install pandas
```

Code:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import pandas as pd

Doc = namedtuple('Doc', 'venue year authors title id references abstract')
docs = []

f = open("content/test.txt", "r")

while(True):
    # Read a line.
    #if not ln.startswith("#t") or not ln.startswith("#index"):
    ln = f.readline()
    print('{} : {}'.format("LINE : ", ln))
    ln = ln.rstrip('\n')
    
    # When readline returns an empty string, the file is fully read.
    if ln == "":
        print("::DONE::")
        break
    # When a newline is returned, the line is empty.
    if ln == "\n":
        #print("::EMPTY LINE::")
        continue
    if ln.startswith('#c'):
        venue = ln[2:]
        print(venue)
    if ln.startswith('#t'):
        year = ln[2:]
        print(year)
    if ln.startswith('#@'):
        authors = []
        while not ln.startswith('#t'):
            if ln.startswith('#@') :
                author = ln[2:]
            else:
                author = ln[0:]
            authors.append(author)
            ln = f.readline()
            print(author)
        f.seek(f.tell() - len(ln))
        ",".join(authors)
    if ln.startswith('#*'):
        title = ln[2:]
        print(title)
    if ln.startswith('#index'):
        id = ln[6:]
        print(id)
    if ln.startswith('#%'):
        references = []
        while not ln.startswith('#!'):
            reference = ln[2:]
            references.append(reference)
            ln = f.readline()
            print(reference)
        ",".join(references)    
    if  ln.startswith('#!'):
        abstract = ln[2:]
        print(abstract)
        docs.append(Doc(venue, year, authors, title, id, references, abstract))

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(docs, columns= 
                ['Venue','Year','Authors','Title','id', 'ListCitations','Abstract'])

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)
print(df)
```

Test input :

```
#*Information geometry of U-Boost and Bregman divergence
#@Nobotu Murata,
Takenouchi
Takafumi Kanamori
#t2004
#cNeural Computation
#index436405
#%94584
#%282290
#%605546
#%620759
#%564878
#!We aim at an extension of AdaBoost to U-Boost
#*Paper 2
#@Tareq 
Shareq
Sameena
#t2016
#cSimulation Computation
#index436406
#%94584
#%282291
#%605543
#%620754
#%323232232232323
#!We aim to conquere the world
```

Output:

```
                Venue  Year  \
```

0      Neural Computation  2004
1  Simulation Computation  2016

```
                                         Authors  \
```

0  [Nobotu Murata,, Takenouchi\n, Takafumi Kanamo...
1                      [Tareq , Shareq\n, Sameena\n]

```
                                           Title      id  \
```

0  Information geometry of U-Boost and Bregman di...  436405
1                                            Paper 2  436406

```
                                   ListCitations  \
```

0    [94584, 282290\n, 605546\n, 620759\n, 564878\n]
1  [94584, 282291\n, 605543\n, 620754\n, 32323223...

```
                                      Abstract
```

0  We aim at an extension of AdaBoost to U-Boost\n
1                   We aim to conquere the world\n

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224235/discussion-on-answer-by-tareq97-reading-a-txt-file-having-lines-starting-with-s).

Answer (score 0):

The code bellow works fine with authors but with references still storing only one element:

```
Doc = namedtuple('Doc', 'venue year authors nba title id references abstract')
docs = []
with open('/content/test.txt') as f:
   for l in f.readlines():
       ln = l.rstrip('\n')
       if  ln.startswith('#c'):
        venue = ln[2:]
        #print(venue)
       if  ln.startswith('#t'):
         year = ln[2:]
         #print(year)
       if  ln.startswith('#@'):
         authors = []
         author = ln[2:]
         authors.append(author)
       else: 
         if not ln.startswith('#') and not ln.startswith(' ') :
            author = ln[0:]
            authors.append(author)
            #print(authors)
            nba = len(authors)
       if  ln.startswith('#*'):
         title = ln[2:]
         #print(title)
       if  ln.startswith('#!'):
         abstract = ln[2:]
       else : 
         if ln.startswith(' '):
           abstract += ln[1:]
           #print(abstract)
       if   ln.startswith('#%'):
           references = []
           reference = ln[2:]
           references.append(reference)    
       else: 
         if  ln.startswith('#%'):
           reference = ln[2:]
           references.append(reference)
           #print(references)
       if  ln.startswith('#index'):
         id = ln[6:]
         docs.append(Doc(venue, year, authors, nba, title, id, references, abstract))
         df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(docs, columns=['Venue','Year','Authors','nba', 'Title','id', 'ListCitations','Abstract'])
df
```

Comment: @tareq97 your code works for only one record (one document)